# Pass a variable using ajax to my current php page without page reloading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am designing a video album.
I want to pass a variable to my php file, using ajax so that when i click on next arrow the next video will be ready to be played. The variable i am trying to pass is the name of the next video. Although i managed to pass the variable with the code i am using the php page reloads with the new variable(so the next video reloads) but all other variables that count which video is selected are taking their initial value. The point is if it is possible to pass the filename variable without page reloading, just video changing.
So i am running this script in my videoalbum.php file. I dont want to reload page so that i can keep the currentImage value.

```
// NEXT ARROW CODE
$('a.nextSlideArrow').click(function() {
$('div.description' + currentImage).removeClass("visible");

currentImage++;

if (currentImage == imagesTotal + 1) {
    currentImage = 1;
}

$('div.description' + currentImage).addClass("visible");
//imagesnames[] is an array with all video files names.
filename = imagesnames[currentImage];

        $.ajax({
            url: 'videoalbum.php',
            type: 'POST',
            //data: {'filename':file},
            success: function() {
                window.location = 'videoalbum.php?filename='+filename;
             }
        });     
return false;
});
```

I am using echo to show the video on my page.
videoalbum.php:

```
   <div class="galleryPreviewContainer">
    <div class="galleryPreviewImage">
        <?php
                if (empty($filename)){
                    echo '<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="900" height="600" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
                    <source src="/uploads/' . $username . '/video/' . $file. '" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="900" height="600" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
                    <source src="/uploads/' . $username . '/video/' . $filename. '" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>';
                }

        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryPreviewArrows">
        <a href="#" id= "previousarrow" class="previousSlideArrow">&lt;</a>
        <a href="#" id="nextarrow" class="nextSlideArrow">&gt;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the page including the video player?  Most javascript based video players allow you to use the API to change the video playing, which would negate the need to try a self-post ajax command to change the video.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback should handle the response from the PHP controller, `videoalbum.php`.

In short:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'videoalbum.php',
    // Use GET for AJAX calls
    type: 'GET',
    data: {'filename':file},
    success: function( response ) {
        // Do something with the response. If your response is a JSON string, then you can play with it
        $('div.description' + currentImage).find('img').attr('src', response.source);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ajax try using `.load()` function. This loads that part of html, after querying into current page div element.

`$(".galleryPreviewImage").load("videoalbum.php .galleryPreviewImage video", {'filename': filename});`

or this

`$(".galleryPreviewImage").load("videoalbum.php?filename="+filename+" .galleryPreviewImage video");`

Comment: didnt thought of that, i am going to try this method and reply